# Apache ignite docker 'image' not compatible on Apple M1 Max

Tags: docker, ignite, apple-m1, gridgain, apple-silicon

docker run -p 10800:10800 apacheignite/ignite:2.11.1

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

How to resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until an ARM image is available, you'll probably have to run it using Rosetta:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -p 10800:10800 apacheignite/ignite:2.11.1
```

Answer (score 3):

On my computer some of containers that works in translation mode (from x86 to arm64) just hangs without any response.

So I've found this repo where Ignite's container are compiled for both `linux/arm64` and `linux/amd64` platforms.

https://hub.docker.com/r/applem1support/ignite/tags

Comment: Thanks @damintsew